# small javascript this problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a list item with a image and text. The text is going over the image. When i hover over the text. Then the text going away and you can see the picture.

I have this html:

```
 <ul>
                    <li><img src="content/img/voorbeeld/projecten.jpg" alt="Project foto" width="209" height="207" />
                        <div class="text">
                            <h4>Nieuwbouw Aalanden Zwolle</h4>
                            <p>Vestibulum eget tristique ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
                            <a href="projecten.html" title="Project details">Project details</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="content/img/voorbeeld/projecten.jpg" alt="Project foto" width="209" height="207" />
                        <div class="text">
                            <h4>Nieuwbouw Woonwijk in Amsterdam</h4>
                            <p>Vestibulum eget tristique ante. In hac wegweg wegweg weg tumst In hac habita abitasse platea dictumstIn hac habitasse platea dictumst.</p>
                            <a href="projecten.html" title="Project details">Project details</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

And this javascript

```
var div     = $(".projects li"); 

    $("#footer .projects li",this).hover(function()
    {       
        if(div.hasClass("open"))
        {
            $(".projects .text").show();
            div.removeClass("open");
        }
        else
        {
            $(".text").hide();
            div.addClass("open");
        }
    });
```

But when i now hover of a li item. All the text of the two li items going away. How can i make it. When i hover over a item, that the other is not going away??

Comment: Any chance on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing what is happening so we can make changes to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided code where does `this` come from, but the code you're using should probably be more along these lines:

```
//               "this" context is unknown from your code
$(".projects li", this).hover(function()
{
    // save jQuery "this" for faster reuse 
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.hasClass("open"))
    {
        $(".text", this).show();
        $this.removeClass("open");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".text", this).hide();
        $this.addClass("open");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tags give you the clue - you need to use this inside of your hover callbacks to make sure you are only dealing with the list item you want to work with, not both.  Right now you are using the variable `div`, which is set to `$('.projects li')`, which means a jQuery object representing *both* list items under projects.  Instead use `this` inside your callbacks.  In the callbacks `this` is set to the element that is being hovered over.

```
$("#footer .projects li", this).hover(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).children(".text").show(); // note - not all .text divs, but only
                                          // children of this list item
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    }
    else {
        $(this).children(".text").hide(); // note - not all .text divs, but only
                                          // children of this list item
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }
});
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/N77Rm/) (sans images, but you get the idea of showing and hiding text).

Comment: This is 100% correct.  As a side note (and I only bring it up for the sake of learning) `$("#footer .projects li")` should be optimized to something like `$("#footer").find(".projects").find("li")`.  Using the original selector, jQuery will find all `LI` elements first, then trace back through their ancestors to discover if they are children of `.projects`, and further children of `#footer`.  The second method is much more efficient (especially if there are many `LI` elements on the page).

Comment: He never said anything about `.text` child nodes only... :S And from the HTML he provided he doesn't have nested `.text` DIVs anyway.

Comment: You're right @Robert.  But one can infer that his problem lies in hiding the `.text` elements by using context clues.

Comment: @Stephen: Are you trying to say that `$("#footer").find(".projects").find("li")` is faster than `$("#footer .projects li")`?

Comment: @Stephen: This was a very interesting info that you've written about speed difference, so I asked a different question on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5900705/75642). Accepted result links a test that tests the difference between the two. Granted it tests with IDs but using `find` is significantly **slower**.

Comment: VERY interesting.  This is a definite departure to the way jQuery and the Sizzle selector engine has handled selectors in the past... more comments to come in your new question.

Answer (score 0):

\\var div     = $(".projects li"); --can remove not required

```
$("#footer .projects li").hover(function() \\this will suffice
{       
    var thisLi = $(this); \\get this for the item that has been hovered
    if(thisLi.hasClass("open"))
    {
        thisLi.find(".text").show();
        thisLi.removeClass("open");
    }
    else
    {
        thisLi.find(".text").hide();
        thisLi.addClass("open");
    }
});
```