# What's faster $("s1").find("s2").find("s3") or $("s1 s2 s3")?

Tags: jquery, comparison, css-selectors

jQuery is quite multifaceted when it comes to selecting certain DOM elements. Today it came to my attention that the two ways of getting the same elements may yield different speed:

```
$("selector1").find("selector2").find("selector3")
```

and

```
$("selector1 selector2 selector3")
```

(where `selectorX` can be ID or class or anything else)

Both produce the same set of elements but are there any speed differences? How does jQuery actually traverse DOM? This is especially important in the second case: does it go from **selector1 to selector3** or **the other way around**?

Anybody measured the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a single `$('...')` is about twice as fast as chaining `$.find()`s for me in Chrome. This [JSPerf Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/nested-find-vs) will give you a good idea of other browsers as well once some more people test it.

Comment: Thanks for providing a runnable test that can be run on different browsers and results observed.

Comment: My FF4 test says that using `find().` is 21% slower than a compound selector.

Comment: Yea it looks like the biggest difference so far is in Chrome/IE

Comment: @jcm: The problem with IE is that it doesn't have native support for  `getElementsByClassName` function which jQuery uses when available.

Comment: The test has been updated to support classes. It looks like classes are actually faster than IDs in IE.

Comment: In FF4 `find` with classes is **a lot** faster than anything else. With IDs it's a bit better to use compound selectors. In my IE8 it looks that using compound selectors is similar with classes and IDs and significantly faster than using `find`. CH10 is fastest with compound IDs followed by `find` with classes. The other two were significantly slower.

Comment: This is awesome.  For a very long time evidence suggested that jQuery traversal functions like `.children()` were notoriously faster than using strings containing multiple selectors.  These tests, however, use the latest jQuery (1.6).  After reviewing your snippets, I tried to do the same tests using the `.children` method, and threw in an element version as well:  http://jsperf.com/nested-children-vs-single-selector  It seems that, in chrome, single selectors win the day.  That is, until you try to traverse using element names.  The traversal method is faster in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Time it yourself and find out!

```
console.time("Selector 1") 
    $("selector1").find("selector2").find("selelector3");
console.timeEnd("Selector 1")

console.time("Selector 2") 
    $("selector1 selector2 selector3");
console.timeEnd("Selector 2")
```

Comment: Run them separately tho. Depending on the browser implementation the work of the first test might impact the work of the second test

Comment: @mattcodes: Maybe I misunderstood you but how can they influence each other if you don't cache any selector results?

Comment: Good point, they should be tested separately. Also, This upvote gave me '1337' rep :D

Comment: You don't cache at javascript level, true, but you dont know what native implementations are doing behind the scenes and watching Google's video about how browsers handle CSS selectors via different buckets etc..  the perform of the methods that interact with native selectors would probably influence the outcome

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the two if you are using classes. `$("selector1 selector2 selector3")` is going to be slower in IE if any (or all) of the selectors are classes because of the lack of support for document.getElementByClassname. Also in IE `$("selector1").find("selector2").find("selector3")` will be slower if selector1 is a class (for the same reason as before). I don't think you will find a cross browser timing due to the different methods available to jQuery code in IE vs FF.

Comment: According to http://jsperf.com/nested-find-vs `$('.class1...')` is actually the fastest. Even faster than IDs.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the findings from @jcm, I decided to test a bit further into these selectors.  I went in with the assumption that a more complex DOM structure would produce much different results.

Here are the tests I created http://jsperf.com/complex-dom-jquery-selectors-vs-traversal-methods

This uses the latest jQuery (v1.6).  It seems that `.find()` is leaps and bounds faster than the other methods of traversal.  This is very interesting news.  For a long time, many users of jQuery (including myself) have offered up the advice that one should use traversal methods, (and typically avoid the find method) instead of selector strings.  So much for that!

I guess the lesson to learn here is that, when absolute performance is a must, rather than depending solely on historical evidence, test your hypotheses.